# Django SearchRank performance with ranked annotations

Tags: django, postgresql, search

I have a well-indexed postgres table with .5 million rows. Doing a direct ORM text search against its fields is lightning fast. However, I would like to get weighted and ranked search results (weighted relevancy). I am doing this:

```
q_ = SearchQuery(val)
qs = Location.objects.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(vector, q_)).filter(
        rank__gte=0.1).order_by('-rank')
```

(vector not shown)

That works, and gives expected ranked results, but it's SLOW. The search time rises from fractional milliseconds to 5+ seconds when rank annotating and ordering is used.

Again, I'm already fully indexed. Is there anything else that can be done to improve performance for weighted search results against large data sets in Django, shy of moving to ElasticSearch or similar?

Comment: I always go with haystack & elasticsearch regardless of the quantity of data. A search index will always out-perform queries on your database so why not just use a proper search index backend? If you've got a well structured DB, adding search indexes is usually really simple.

Comment: Really trying to avoid adding complexity to the stack, but yes, we may have to go there if we want proper ranking. Thanks.